# xunit testing IdentityServer Quickstart UI - Issue mocking login

Tags: c#, mocking, moq, identityserver4, xunit

I am trying to create XUnit tests for the AccountController that comes from the QuickStart UI and am having a lot of trouble figuring out what I need to mock in order to get the Login function to succeed.
Login_return_Redirect ends up with the following exception:

```
Source: AccountTests.cs line 101
   Duration: 2 sec

  Message: 
    System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Stack Trace: 
    AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
    FederatedSignoutAuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
    DefaultUserSession.AuthenticateAsync()
    DefaultUserSession.GetUserAsync()
    DefaultUserSession.CreateSessionIdAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal, AuthenticationProperties properties)
    IdentityServerAuthenticationService.SignInAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, ClaimsPrincipal principal, AuthenticationProperties properties)
    AuthenticationManagerExtensions.SignInAsync(HttpContext context, IdentityServerUser user, AuthenticationProperties properties)
    AuthenticationManagerExtensions.SignInAsync(HttpContext context, String subject, String name, AuthenticationProperties properties, Claim[] claims)
    AccountController.Login(LoginInputModel model, String button) line 130
    AccountTests.Login_return_Redirect() line 104
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

The function I'm testing:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Handle postback from username/password login
        /// </summary>
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model, string button)
        {
            // check if we are in the context of an authorization request
            var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(model.ReturnUrl);

            // the user clicked the "cancel" button
            if (button != "login")
            {
                if (context != null)
                {
                    // if the user cancels, send a result back into IdentityServer as if they 
                    // denied the consent (even if this client does not require consent).
                    // this will send back an access denied OIDC error response to the client.
                    await _interaction.GrantConsentAsync(context, ConsentResponse.Denied);

                    // we can trust model.ReturnUrl since GetAuthorizationContextAsync returned non-null
                    if (await _clientStore.IsPkceClientAsync(context.ClientId))
                    {
                        // if the client is PKCE then we assume it's native, so this change in how to
                        // return the response is for better UX for the end user.
                        return View("Redirect", new RedirectViewModel { RedirectUrl = model.ReturnUrl });
                    }

                    return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    // since we don't have a valid context, then we just go back to the home page
                    return Redirect("~/");
                }
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // validate username/password against in-memory store
                if (_users.ValidateCredentials(model.Username, model.Password))
                {
                    var user = _users.FindByUsername(model.Username);
                    await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.Username, user.SubjectId, user.Username, clientId: context?.ClientId));

                    // only set explicit expiration here if user chooses "remember me". 
                    // otherwise we rely upon expiration configured in cookie middleware.
                    AuthenticationProperties props = null;
                    if (AccountOptions.AllowRememberLogin && model.RememberLogin)
                    {
                        props = new AuthenticationProperties
                        {
                            IsPersistent = true,
                            ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(AccountOptions.RememberMeLoginDuration)
                        };
                    };

                    // issue authentication cookie with subject ID and username
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.SubjectId, user.Username, props);

                    if (context != null)
                    {
                        if (await _clientStore.IsPkceClientAsync(context.ClientId))
                        {
                            // if the client is PKCE then we assume it's native, so this change in how to
                            // return the response is for better UX for the end user.
                            return View("Redirect", new RedirectViewModel { RedirectUrl = model.ReturnUrl });
                        }

                        // we can trust model.ReturnUrl since GetAuthorizationContextAsync returned non-null
                        return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                    }

                    // request for a local page
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                    }
                    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect("~/");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // user might have clicked on a malicious link - should be logged
                        throw new Exception("invalid return URL");
                    }
                }

                await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginFailureEvent(model.Username, "invalid credentials", clientId:context?.ClientId));
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, AccountOptions.InvalidCredentialsErrorMessage);
            }

            // something went wrong, show form with error
            var vm = await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(model);
            return View(vm);
        }
```

My current test setup:

```
public class AccountTests
    {
        private readonly TestUserStore _users;
        private readonly IIdentityServerInteractionService _interaction;
        private readonly IClientStore _clientStore;
        private readonly IAuthenticationSchemeProvider _schemeProvider;
        private readonly IEventService _events;

        AccountController _controller;
        TestServer _server;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor that sets up the MVC pipeline and creates the controller instance
        /// </summary>
        public AccountTests()
        {
            var webhost = new WebHostBuilder()
                    .UseUrls("http://*:8000")
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();

            _server = new TestServer(webhost);


            _users = (TestUserStore)_server.Services.GetService(typeof(TestUserStore));
            _interaction = (IIdentityServerInteractionService)_server.Services.GetService(typeof(IIdentityServerInteractionService));
            _clientStore = (IClientStore)_server.Services.GetService(typeof(IClientStore)); 
            _schemeProvider = (IAuthenticationSchemeProvider)_server.Services.GetService(typeof(IAuthenticationSchemeProvider));
            _events = (IEventService)_server.Services.GetService(typeof(IEventService));

            _controller = new AccountController(_interaction, _clientStore, _schemeProvider, _events, _users);

            // configuring the HTTP context and user principal,
            // in order to be able to use the User.Identity.Name property in the controller action
            var validPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(
                new[]
                {
                        new ClaimsIdentity(
                            new[] {new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "testsuser@testinbox.com") })
                });

            var mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>(MockBehavior.Strict);
            mockHttpContext.SetupGet(hc => hc.User).Returns(validPrincipal);
            mockHttpContext.SetupGet(c => c.Items).Returns(new Dictionary<object, object>());
            mockHttpContext.SetupGet(ctx => ctx.RequestServices)
                .Returns(_server.Services);

            var collection = Mock.Of<IFormCollection>();
            var request = new Mock<HttpRequest>();
            request.Setup(f => f.ReadFormAsync(CancellationToken.None)).Returns(Task.FromResult(collection));

            var mockHeader = new Mock<IHeaderDictionary>();
            mockHeader.Setup(h => h["X-Requested-With"]).Returns("XMLHttpRequest");
            request.SetupGet(r => r.Headers).Returns(mockHeader.Object);

            mockHttpContext.SetupGet(c => c.Request).Returns(request.Object);

            var response = new Mock<HttpResponse>();
            response.SetupProperty(it => it.StatusCode);

            mockHttpContext.Setup(c => c.Response).Returns(response.Object);


            _controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext()
            {
                HttpContext = mockHttpContext.Object
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Task</returns>
        [Fact]
        public async Task Login_returns_ViewResult()
        {
            var request = await _controller.Login("");
            Assert.IsAssignableFrom<ViewResult>(request);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Login_return_Redirect()
        {

                var request = await _controller.Login(new LoginInputModel { Username = "alice", Password = "alice", RememberLogin = false, ReturnUrl = "" }, "login");
                Assert.IsAssignableFrom<RedirectResult>(request);


        }


    }
```

Comment: seems to me that you messed up a bit. Why do you spin up TestServer and then instantiate the controller? If you spin up a web server during your test you don't need to instantiate controller, you need http client to call the endpoint. Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1) about integration tests in ASP

Comment: I spun up the testserver so I could retrieve the DI pieces that are required to create the controller. I couldn't figure out how to make half of them to mock up from IdentityServer so I could actually test my controller methods. If there's a better way please let me know. Ultimately I'm trying to test the controller methods not the html result that comes back via the view.

Comment: You should be able to Mock all the dependencies otherwise you won't be able to test your controller. If you cannot mock everything you inject into the controller, then you need to create abstractions (interfaces or abstracts classes) to your instances. Because what you are trying to do now isn't right

Comment: The problem I have with that is that all of those things come from IdentityServer4. The current exception occurs on a function from that component and a reference exception doesn't tell me enough about what is missing. Ideas?